# Return value of the getUpdateCounts() of theh mssql-jdbc driver which comes with com.microsoft.sqlserver

Tags: java, batch-processing, mssql-jdbc, jtds

Currently I'm processing a batch of data which saves into MSSQL database.
And I'm using this jtds driver to get establish the database transactions.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

While processing the batch I'm expecting there can be some rows which fail while inserting.
I want to get to know exactly what are the failed rows for my requirement.

I used this getUpdateCounts() method to find the status of the processed records in the batch.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/BatchUpdateException.html

But I'm not getting the expected result from this method.
Assume the first record success and the second one failed.
then the out put is something like this.

```
[-2, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3]
```

And if the first one fails and others success, still it's resulting like this way.

```
[-3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3]
```

Then I thought of using the mssql-jdbc driver instead of the jtds driver.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>12.4.1.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

For run the project with this driver change, I have to do several changes in the project.

So I'm expecting valuable thoughts regarding this scenario.

Comment: afaicr jtds died some time ago and shouldn't be considered reliable now. Use the latest driver from MS

Comment: If you are using at least Java 8, then you need version 1.3.1 (and not 1.2.8)

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _For run the project with this driver change, I have to do several changes in the project._ As far as I am aware (or afaiaa - as @g00se would write), those changes are very minor. We initially used [jTDS](https://jtds.sourceforge.net/) and moved to [Microsoft JDBC driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) and only required very minimal changes.

Comment: yeah, useful thoughts, have anyone got the output of the getUpdateCounts() method, in a real world scenario?

Comment: Are you sure the rest of your batch is even getting executed? if sql server aborted your batch after first failure, the rest of the batches will be populated with failures automatically. we need some sort of code that reproduces the issue i think. Also, you're using an old jtds version (which is itself very old).